# Will ROS Noetic support Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now that Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is out and Ros Noetic is the final ROS1 distro, will it be supported on Ubuntu 22? For people with newer hardware (i.e. Alder Lake CPUs) this will definitely be a must.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399664/will-ros-noetic-support-ubuntu-22.04?/) by [nissen22](https://answers.ros.org/users/103231/nissen22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2022-04-26

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Pedantic -- so please forgive me @lucasw -- but to make this crystal clear for (future) readers:

**no**, ROS Noetic will *not* officially support Ubuntu `22.04`.

Refer to [REP-3: Target Platforms: Noetic Ninjemys (May 2020 - May 2025)](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#noetic-ninjemys-may-2020-may-2025), specifically the sections about supported operating systems.

This will not be changed for ROS Noetic.

You *can* build ROS Noetic from source on Ubuntu `22.04`, as @lucasw describes.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2023-04-06**:
Running a ros1 release in a docker container is now viable, so this is an option. Pre-built docker containers for various ros releases are available on hub.docker.com.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-04-07**:
Of course. Docker / LXC / some other containerisation technology would (almost) always be an option.

It doesn't change the answer though: Noetic officially only supports `20.04`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Core ros components are in debian https://wiki.debian.org/DebianScience/Robotics/ROS/Packages and a few more are on the way so you can apt install them without using packages.ros.org (but if you are in 20.04 still you don't want to mix and match the debian and packages.ros.org ones).  But probably a lot you want to use will need building from source.

I've had good results building **everything**  from source on 22.04 but I expect I'll be able to swap out some of that for the debian packages next time I go through it (that process is in https://github.com/lucasw/ros_from_src but it's messy in there currently).
(https://answers.ros.org/question/402081/build-ros-noetic-in-ubuntu-2204/ has a more updated answer to building from source now)

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2022-04-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-04-27**:
While this provides some encouraging information about whether it would be possible to *build* ROS Noetic on `22.04`, technically this is not an answer.

The question was: "will ROS Noetic support Ubuntu 22.04?"

The only correct answer would be: "No, it will not, officially".

ROS Noetic is slated to be the last ROS 1 release, and officially will not support anything beyond Ubuntu Focal (or `20.04`).

There is a community effort to keep things building though: [github.com/ros-o](https://github.com/ros-o). Not just on newer Ubuntu versions, but newer versions of other Linux OS as well.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2022-04-30**:\

> this provides some encouraging information about whether it would be possible to *build* ROS Noetic on 22.04

The debian.org packages are pre-built, so can be pulled down through apt (similar to packages.ros.org for 20.04, but sometimes with name changes that make it unclear what was previously ros-noetic-foo corresponds to), so for a ros project with only core dependencies it wouldn't need to build them from scratch.  I can't attest to that from experience yet though, but will update here when I do.

As I understand it `ros-o` and the debian.org packages are the same (minus more recent commits in ros-o that haven't been released yet)- maybe a few of the released debian.org ros packages needed no alteration to build in 22.04 (or other Linux OSes with more updated dependencies that are turning deprecations warnings into outright build failures etc.) and they didn't fork them there.  I used the ros-o sources to build from scratch.